# How do i add my own header on ios/swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to add this particular header to my iphone app which lives in UIViewController

The current implementation

[image]

the restaurant header.[image]

What I want to achieve

The only solution that I could think of to add this particular header is using image view in object library

How do i do add it?

Comment: Question is unclear! You want to add header? Where? In UITableView? UICollectionView? UIView? Where?

Comment: For tableView, you can work with Xib custom headers, look at this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926612/swift-how-creating-custom-viewforheaderinsection-using-a-xib-file

Answer (score 1):

Use the `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method to customise table section headerView

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
}
```

and don't forget to implement the method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works

set the section header height in the `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = your desired height(in int)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 18))
    let imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50))

    self.view.addSubview(imageview)

    return view
}
```

set images in your imageview according to your requirements