# How to programatically register a UITableViewHeaderFooterView in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I need my tableView to fire an event for:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
```

to do that, according to the documentation, I can't just add a view to the tableView like this:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = spaceView
```

which, whilst working, doesn't make that function get fired, nor does the table dequeue the footer despite how long the table might get.

I can't do this in the storyboard / XIB because whether a footer is added or not, is a decision only made at runtime.

So according to the documentation or at least my understanding of them, I have to make 'spaceView' a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView and I have to do a formal 'register' to add it into the tableView, like this:

```
let spaceView = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(reuseIdentifier: "emptyFooter")

tableView.register(spaceView, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "emptyFooter")
```

But then I get a compile error:

```
Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UITableViewHeaderFooterView, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String)'
```

So, despite the docs, any ideas how I'm reading the doc's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926612/swift-how-creating-custom-viewforheaderinsection-using-a-xib-file

Comment: Nope. Yet again, as I said, no XIB, and no method returning a default FOOTER VIEW  as in your suggestion below.

Comment: Wait. Do you **one** footer at the bottom of the table view? Or do you want **one footer per section**?

Comment: One at the end of the entire table - there will be only one section.

Comment: In that case you have to go with `tableView.tableFooterView = yourFooterView`. The `didEndDisplayingFooterView` delegate function only gets called for section footers. What are you trying to achieve with that function?

Comment: As I said at the beginning of my question, I did that, but I need that function to get called. Because the app has 1 section, because it has too, that method I need firing should still get called. According to the docs, it won't get called unless the FOOTER VIEW has been added correctly - with a 'register' command.

Comment: @AndréSlotta What I'm trying to achieve, is knowing when the footer is no longer visible on screen and then removing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but none of these either addressed the problem, or led to a solution.

Instead, I have the functionality, exactly as I wanted it, with just a small function of 6 lines of code and one private property on the view controller.

As soon as the tableView.footerView goes 'offscreen' it's instantly set to nil, and it's only created exactly when I want it to be.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer to your question is:

```
class CustomTableViewHeaderFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView { }

class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewHeaderFooterView")
    }
}
```

Then you can use the registered header / footer view like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let customFooterView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewHeaderFooterView")
    // set up your footer view
    return customFooterView
}
```

To achieve what you explained in your comments though you do not have to register any `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. Instead you can use the table view's `tableFooterView` and implement the functionality yourself. Try this inside your `UITableViewController` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.backgroundColor = .orange
    footerView.frame.size.height = 44

    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
}

var footerViewIsVisible = false {
    didSet {
        if !footerViewIsVisible && oldValue {
            tableViewDidEndDisplayingTableFooterView(tableView)
        }
    }
}

func tableViewDidEndDisplayingTableFooterView(_ tableView: UITableView) {
    print("didEndDisplayingTableFooterView")
    tableView.tableFooterView = nil
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if let tableFooterView = tableView.tableFooterView {
        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: scrollView.contentOffset, size: scrollView.bounds.size)
        self.footerViewIsVisible = visibleRect.intersects(tableFooterView.frame)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 60))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 30/255, blue: 32/255, alpha: 1.0)
    return headerView
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping but that doesn't work for me. I need to have or not have a FOOTER depending on other code and tests that occur in other functions. It's not a global - always return this view sort of problem.